# Laravel 5.6: How to pass selected value from Dropdown list to PHP variable on the same page by Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm using Laravel 5.6 and PHP 7.1.9. I Have this selected box, and the PHP condition on the same page to check the value of checkbox selected, and then to do some tasks:
(pages/cardview.blade.php)

```
 <select name="" id="">
                    <option value="All" disabled selected>All Status</option>
                    <option value="Available">Available</option>
                    <option value="Not Available">Not Available</option>
                    <option value="Partial Available">Partial Available</option>

                </select>


@if($The_DropDownList_Value == "Available")
     {{ $The_DropDownList_Value }}
@endif


@if($The_DropDownList_Value == "Not Available")
     {{ $The_DropDownList_Value }}
@endif
```

I want to pass the selected value to the PHP variable ($The_DropDownList_Value )by using Ajax and JS. How to get the Selected value box and pass it to PHP variable to check the value and to some tasks in the condition.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming you are using jQuery. $('#idofselecttag > option:selected).val() will give you the selected option value

Comment: Where is the Ajax part?

Comment: [Did you already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51927373/how-to-pass-selected-value-from-dropdown-list-by-ajax-to-php-variables-in-larave)

Comment: @AfrazAhmad By jquery I can send the selected value and assign it to PHP variable ( $The_DropDownList_Value ) ??

Comment: you can not assign js value to php easily. but you can get selected value and save in js variable and send via ajax as you asked in your question.

Comment: @kerbholz I tried many tutorials to do it, and search for JS Functions but cant solve it. Can u guide me to solve my issue.

Comment: @AfrazAhmad yes, This is what I need, I'm still beginner in Ajax, and now I face this issue in laravel, I search in Google and others, but in laravel not have much same of my problem, can u guide me through the solution by example.

Comment: sure let me show you in answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your select tag has id

> selectedYourChoice

then your js code will be like this:

```
 var selectedOption = '';
selectedOption = $('#selectedYourChoice > option:selected').val();
```

//now selected option value is saved in js  selectedOption.

**Ajax**

```
$.ajax({
 type:"GET",
 url:"url here",
 data: "{data: selectedOption}",
 .done(function(response){
       console.log(response.data);
  }).
  fail(function(error){
       console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, What about the route and Controller part. No need for them ? Thats great, I will try it and inform you, ;)